# How to provide custom software for easy installation on pi?

Tags: software-installation, software-development

I've seen several useful scripts programs that someone created for Raspberry Pi. Installation, however often requires to install dependent packages, manually create files and directories, copying and adjusting files etc. What's the easiest way to provide such software in a way it can simply be installed, updated, and removed with one command? I suppose one could create a Debian package but I doubt that everyone contributing to Raspberry Pi software is willing to learn details of Debian package management. Maybe there is some easier way, a simple tutorial, or sample software for Raspberry Pi that one could reuse?

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only a select few operating systems used on the Raspberry Pi I would suggest detecting which distribution is being used and handle software installation using that distros default package manager.

This way you don't have to overcome any cross-distribution differences and software can be packaged as simple `tar` files.